# Can an Android app detect ADB commands?

Tags: android, adb

Is there anyway an app could detect if it was launched (or killed) via an ADB command line code from an attached computer vs physically tapping the actual app icon on the screen?

And/or could it tell if a tap input in the app was done by a physical tap vs an ADB input?

Launch command:  adb shell monkey -p  -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

Kill command: adb shell am force-stop

Tap command: adb shell input tap

Comment: I don't think that it can.

Comment: Thanks.  If anyone knows for SURE, please chime in.

Answer (score 1):

adb command is running in a brandnew process of `system/bin/sh`. It is difficult to achieve，even if the device is rooted.

You maybe need handle touch events via `getevent` command. `adb shell input` will skip the input device to simulate user action, but if someone uses the `adb shell sendevent` command, you will not be able to detect it.